# add body class to wordpress based on user role

Tags: php, wordpress

can't find any plugin to help out for my needs

I have NextGen Gallery installed , I have 2 public galleries and several private galleries. I have a custom image search for the site and even though my private galleries are password protected , when using the image search , the NextGen gallery images within the locked galleries are displaying in the public search also.

So i was thinking about adding a body class and hide images based on user role , or even better would be some script to hide images in that gallery id based on user role.

Any ideas guys ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a feature request
http://wordpress.org/plugins/nextgen-gallery/

Also, granular control on users achieved by:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-access-manager/